# What is the `next` in applyMiddleware()?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I am reading the source code of `applyMiddleware`, and in some snippet, they call it this way `applyMiddleware(...middleware)`. So when does the `next` parameter get passed?

```
export default function applyMiddleware(...middlewares) {
  return (next)  =>
     (reducer, initialState) => {
        var store = next(reducer, initialState);
        var dispatch = store.dispatch;
        var chain = [];

        var middlewareAPI = {
          getState: store.getState,
          dispatch: (action) => dispatch(action)
        };

        chain = middlewares.map(middleware => middleware(middlewareAPI));

        dispatch = compose(...chain, store.dispatch);
        return {
          ...store,
          dispatch
        };
   };
}
```

Comment: have you read [**`applyMiddleware`**](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/applyMiddleware.html) docs?

Answer (score 0):

Each `middleware` in `middlewares` has this general format:

```
// condensed, does not do anything, just calls the next middleware
function middleware({ getState }) => (next) => (action) => next(action)

or

// expanded, does not do anything, just calls the next middleware
function middleware({ getState }) {
  return function (next) {
    return function (action) {
      return next(action)
    }
  }
}
```

A middleware is a function returning a function returning a function invoking the next middleware should there be any.

To answer your question, `next` gets passed as an argument to the second function. This way, the `applyMiddleware` store enhancer can call the next middleware in the chain. The middleware syntax is a bit confusing (from the [docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/applyMiddleware.html)):

> Middleware sounds much more complicated than it really is. The only
>   way to really understand middleware is to see how the existing
>   middleware works, and try to write your own. The function nesting can
>   be intimidating, but most of the middleware you'll find are, in fact,
>   10-liners, and the nesting and composability is what makes the
>   middleware system powerful.